# Looking to find a C++ STL vector inside an STL vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, find

I am trying to see if vector *v1* is contained within vector *v2*. My vectors are ordered and it is required that the order is preserved.

For example, if *v1= (**a, b**)* and *v2 = (e, f, **a, b**)*, I would like to get an iterator pointing to **a** in *v2*.

STL `find` only finds one object inside a vector. I guess what I want is something similar to `string::find`.

Is there any function in STL for doing this?

Comment: When you say your vectors are ordered, do you mean that they are ordered by some criteria such that you can compare one element to another to determine which one comes first?  Or do you mean that you have set them out in a specific order that cannot be derived just by looking at elements and comparing them, but is dependent on somthing outside?

Comment: [std::includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) may help, but don't know what ordering is used in your case.

Comment: By ordered I mean I have used STL vector to model an ordered list which cannot be derived just by looking at elements and comparing them. I need to find out if the members of v1 appeared in v2 in the same order. I cannot sort the vector. Just like you don't sort a string when you search it for occurring of another string.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you want to search for a subsequence inside another sequence. You can do that with [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) from the Standard Library.

```
auto it = std::search(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
```